How do I prevent normal users from logging in during system maintenance?
What can I do in Ubuntu for preventing normal users from logging in during system maintenance?
(This is on a server where user accounts are just local user accounts, not network accounts.)
man 5 nologin tells us that we could create a file /etc/nologin, and that then:

login(1) will allow access only to root. Other users will be shown the contents of this file and their logins will be refused

Does this still work literally as described on Ubuntu (restricting logins to allow only the literal root account - which would put us in an "unhelpful" situation as root is of course normally disabled on Ubuntu) or has it maybe been patched on Ubuntu to instead allow only members of the sudo group to login?
If this isn't an appropriate solution, are my options then limited to, for each normal user, doing one of the following (and then reverting again afterwards):

sudo chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin username
sudo passwd -l username

Or is there another technique that I could use to temporarily prevent normal users from logging in?

At my workplace we send an email.

At my workplace we sadly know that some of our users don't ~read~ properly ingest emails and sadly will try to login anyway, unless prevented from doing so! :-(

The main function of the /etc/nologin file is to display a message to users attempting to log into a system.
Once the message has been displayed to the user, the login process is terminated, preventing the user from logging into the system.
This can be used to block login by manually creating the file before starting system maintenance, with the following command:
sudo nano /etc/nologin

And adding the text to display for example:

The server is undergoing maintenance. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Once the maintenance is complete, the file is deleted and everything remains as before.
-------Edited---------
Provided by: manpages-en_4.21.0-2_all
NAME
nologin - prevents unprivileged users from logging in
DESCRIPTION
If the file /etc/nologin exists and is writable, login(1) will only allow root access. Any other user will be shown the contents of this file and will be denied access. This is a simple way to prevent non-root users from logging in.
FILES
/etc/nologin
Situation
SSH users using non-password authentication (such as public key authentication) can still log in despite the file /etc/nologin being present.
Resolution
Edit /etc/pam.d/sshd and change the line
auth     requisite      pam_nologin.so

to
account  requisite      pam_nologin.so

Additional Information
The default PAM setup allowing SSH login via public key authentication despite the presence of /etc/nologin avoids accidently locking out remote monitoring scripts or (non-root) administrative staff when just regular users, which in most modern installations log in via a remote X11 server or VNC anyway, aren't supposed to log in.
-------End------

I think this does not answer the question about what happens to non-root account(s) that the system administrator(s) need(s) to log in to do root stuff operations with sudo.

You should read the content of a question and not only it's heading. :)

It would be nice to explain how exactly this would happen: (1) "Once the maintenance is complete, the file is deleted and everything remains as before" (2) Does this still work literally as described on Ubuntu (restricting logins to allow only the literal root account - which would put us in an "unhelpful" situation as root is of course normally disabled on Ubuntu). Thanks.

Yes, I don't want to find out the hard way whether /etc/nologin on Ubuntu also locks me out (as I will also be a (semi-)normal user before I use sudo), hence asking the question. If my ssh connection drops and I have to reconnect, I might also then find myself locked out (and, for this specific server, for reasons (yes, sorry) we also have several people with sudo powers responsible for different aspects of maintenance, and we can't really expect them all to ssh in simultaneously before we 'nologin' the ordinary users.)

As you already figured out, Ubuntu will not allow any non-root user to login after you set the /etc/nologin file.
As a dirty, but easy solution, you can use something like this to ensure members of the sudo group can log in while others cannot:
Append a custom PAM rule to the /etc/pam.d/login file like this:
auth required pam_exec.so /path/to/nologin-script.sh

Create the relevant script file:
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/local/nologin ] && ! groups "$PAM_USER" | grep -q -w sudo ; then
  exit 1
fi
exit 0

Don't forget to make the script file executable!
To prevent new logins from non-sudoers type:
$ sudo touch /var/local/nologin

To resume to normal operations:
$ sudo rm /var/local/nologin

Note, that this does not prevent graphical user logins.
And you should also devise a method to kick out users that are already logged in!

Very elegant solution, that can stay in place and get automatically provisionned on every server (as long as you're sure all your servers use sudo as the group name as opposed to wheel). I'm just concerned about the re-use of /etc/nologin as the existing mechanisms surrounding this file should also kick in, no?

Yes. You are right @Themoonisacheese . I updated my answer.
